# How to use serializer method field to work on primary key related data

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to use serializer method field to fetch data with some business rule

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Stock(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.Cascade, related_name='stock')
    current = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()

class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    productstock = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    #GET LATEST CURRENT STOCK-QUANTITU
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = [

            'name',
            'productstock'
        ]
```

I want to get an output like this:
{
name:'laptop',
productstock:18

}

Comment: Hi friend have you solved this issue ?

Answer (score 2):

I was not able check it right now but it should be something like this:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    productstock = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    #GET LATEST CURRENT STOCK-QUANTITU
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = [
            'name',
            'productstock'
        ]

    def get_productstock(self, obj):
        stock = Stock.objects.filter(product__name=obj.name)
        return stock.quantity
```

**Explanation:**

the serializer method is always built up by get_ + variable_name and takes the curren object as an argument. Then you should be able to filter your Stock model and the productstock value will become what you return by this method. Hope it helps you.

**Update**

I guess now I got your point. You should do the filtering before you pass your queryset through the serializer. Therefore I would recommend to override the get_queryset method. In your view just add the below function and it just filters only the products with current=True. My example is with APIView but it works with every DRF View as they all inherit the APIView.

```
class YourViewClass(APIView):

...

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Product.objects.filter(stock__current=True)
```

**Explanation**

Within the filter method you refer to your related_name of the foreign key field and then use double underscore plus the field you want to filter on. Hope it works for you.

Comment: Thanks. but my problem is to get the current=True Stock only

Comment: Does it now has the output you are trying to achieve?